# How can I sum rows 1 and 3 of my matrix in Matlab with the function sum()?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, sum

I have matrix `A= [1 1 4; 4 4 2; 1 2 4]` and I need to sum the first and third row together and get `(1+1+4)+(1+2+4)` using functions of Matlab, such as `sum()`, not only `while` and `for`. I know how to count it one by one, using `for`.

I tried to use `sum` in different ways, but I always get the sum of the whole matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of working with Matlab is accessing rows and columns of arrays. This is a reasonable first problem.

```
%Input
A = [1 1 4; 4 4 2; 1 2 4]

%Written out, row sum
out_1 = A(1,:) + A(3,:)

%Using the sum function, row sum
out_2 = sum(  A([1 3],:)  )

%To get the desired single value, I usually use `sum` twice, like this
out_scalar = sum(sum(  A([1 3],:)  ))

%But, if you are using 2018b or later, you can do this instead
out_scalar = sum(  A([1 3],:) , 'all')
```

Comment: This produces a vector output, not a scalar as desired by OP.

Comment: You're right. I've added an edit.

Comment: Or out_scalar = sum(  A([1 3],:) , 'all'  )

Comment: I didn't know about 'all'!  Looks like it was added in 2018b.  I'll add this to my list of reasons to upgrade from 2018a.